# UITableViewCell dynamic height

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've done a lot of reading already on this, but it's seems like there's no simple solution.

I'm trying to make an app that loads an `NSArray` of `NSString` comments to display in a `UITableView`. The comments all vary in size.

How can I get the cell to adjust its size to show the entire content of each comments?

I'm trying to find a simple solution without resorting to using magic `CFloat` numbers.

Is there a method in apple's API that allows me to calculate the needed height of the `cell.detailTextLabel` given an `NSString` comment and fixed width?

I think if I can calculate this height, all that's need is to set the height of the cell and the height of the row.

Not really sure what order to do this in since I've read the cell hasn't been created yet when `heightForRow:AtIndexPath:` gets called.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS calculate text height in tableView cell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14841193/ios-calculate-text-height-in-tableview-cell)

Comment: possible duplicate [Dynamic Height of UITableViewCell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744277/dynamic-height-of-uitableviewcell?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate the height of the text in `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`

You need to use  `boundingRectWithSize:options:context:` on iOS 7+ and `sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:` on iOS 6 and below. See the apple documentation for more information.

```
UIFont   *font    = [UIFont oka_commentLabelFont];
NSString *text    = [self commentForIndexPath:indexPath];
CGFloat cellWidth = 300.f;

CGSize boundingSize = CGSizeMake(widthForCell, CGFLOAT_MAX);
CGSize size;

if ([text respondsToSelector:@selector(boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:)]) {
  size = [text boundingRectWithSize:boundingSize
                            options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                         attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName : font }
                            context:nil].size;
} else {
  size = [text sizeWithFont:font
          constrainedToSize:boundingSize
              lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakModeWordWrap];
}

return size.height;
```

You need to set the font to the same font you want to use on the cell. If you put this in a `performUpdates` block on the `tableView` then you will get a nice expanding animation.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. My text still end in ellipsis but the cell is now huge.

Comment: Have you set the auto-resizing mask on the label? maker sure it has resizable height. If you use IB its easy, see the image: http://www.techotopia.com/images/2/27/Iphone_view_autosize_height_width.jpg

You will want it everything checked - so its red.

Comment: Do you mean auto layout 4 sides constraint on the label in storyboard? I tried doing that but it won't let me.

Comment: Turn auto-layout off for the cell nib, just use auto-resizing masks it will be good enough for your needs.

Comment: I tried this in -cellForRowAtIndexPath,                         [cell setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
cell.autoresizingMask= UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight; It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Using your code seems to compress the height of the cell for some reason. I logged them and they all came out to 22.0. The width seems to be changing. I also logged my comments and they all came out normally.

Comment: Hey, I've seemed to fix it, but in some cells, there's still too much free space on top and at the botton.

Comment: Are you using the correct width input? e.g. if your cell is 200px wide, make sure it reflects whats in the height for row. Another thing to check is to make sure the font is the same!

Comment: I tried playing around with the font size. Some cell is a little bit too tight and some have too much room. Not sure what to do, but instead of using subtitle cell, I chose the custom option and added my own labels with constraint.

Comment: Place the label on a UIView which is 10px in from the left and 10px in from the right, that way it wont hug the edges of the view. Move this to chat if you want to discuss further

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45584/discussion-between-user3142893-and-oliver-atkinson)

Answer (score 1):

Don't set the height of the cell, set the height of the row and the table view will do the rest.

To calculate the height of the text, ask a label with `textRectForBounds:limitedToNumberOfLines:`, or ask the string with one of the many methods like `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:`.

You may need to deal with padding around the label when compared to the size of the cell.

Comment: So once I set my comments NSString to the `cell.detailTextLabel`, I use `textRectForBounds:limitedToNumberOfLines:` ? But the thing is, I'm not assigning my comments until cellForRowAtIndexPath, so my cell.detailTextLabel is still nil when heightForRowAtIndexPath gets called.

Comment: No, you should have an array of strings or something like that. Use the string from there in `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`

Answer (score 0):

yes we can calculate the height of `UILabel` depending on the Font and line break mode.

```
UIFont * font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
CGSize newSize = [text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font}];// You can add other attributes in dictionary to like line break mode.
```

Here you got new size for the text which will be in `UILabel`, now in `hegihtForCellAtIndexPath` method you can change the size of `UITableViewCell`. `newSize.height` is height you need for `label`, now you can add some value to it for offsets and return it.

Comment: sizeWithFont is deprecated though. Is 296 the maximum with of a cell? What if I'm trying to make my code more usable to adjust to the ipad and other devices?  I'm not sure where I would put your code in, heightForRowAtIndexPath? People keep saying that the cell and its textlabel is still nil when heightForRowAtIndexPath gets called.

Comment: In your new code, when are you using maximumLabelSize variable? Do you just throw it in the dictionary that passes to sizeWithAttribute?

Comment: This is not required now, I am removing this.

Comment: You can use systemfont with size 12 if you not have custom cell

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
   return [super tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

Comment: How is this different from omitting the implementation of `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`?

Comment: Are you suggesting that I use this if I decide to subclass UITableView or UITableViewCell? Because I'm trying to find a simple solution without resorting to subclassing. I don't want to do a lot of coding to find out Apple has some simple method to solve this.